# If $x\lt y$ then prove that $\lfloor x\rfloor \leq \lfloor y\rfloor $.

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If  $x\lt y$ then we have to show  $\lfloor x\rfloor \leq \lfloor y\rfloor $ for any real numbers $x,y$.

I have proceeded in the following way:  for any real numbers $x,y$,

$x-1\lt \lfloor x\rfloor \leq  x\lt \lfloor x\rfloor+1 $ and

$y-1\lt \lfloor y\rfloor \leq  y \lt \lfloor y\rfloor+1 $. From these we have $ \lfloor x\rfloor \lt  y$ and  $ \lfloor y\rfloor \leq y$ .

I`m stuck here. What can I do after this to prove the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $\lfloor y\rfloor$ is the **largest** integer $\leq y$, and similarly for $\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Then $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an integer $\leq x\leq y$. Since $\lfloor y\rfloor$ is the largest such, we get the result.

Comment: @LC thank you for your answer(+1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x< y$ and let $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$. We have two cases:

1) if $y<n+1$ then $\lfloor x\rfloor=n=\lfloor y\rfloor$;

2) if $y\geq n+1$ then $\lfloor x\rfloor=n<n+1\leq \lfloor y\rfloor$.

Comment: `s thank you for your answer in  different way(+1)